# How to wait in a continuous loop in servlet?

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

I am developing a servlet based application. One situation is that a client requests some data from a database which is sent back in the form of html. The client will modify this data and then sent it back to the server. Now the twist starts. There is not a single client. So multiple clients can request the same data. So what I am doing is that when the first client makes a request, this request is stored somewhere so that when the next user makes the same request he is denied the data.

Now suppose the first user gets the data and 2nd is denied. Now while the first user is on the html page which allows him to modify the data. I want to send continuous javascript async post requests at a fixed interval to inform the server that the client is active.

At the server side I need a thread or something which can keep waiting in a loop for the javascript async requests and if the request is not received within the fixed time then the thread removes the saved request so that future requests to the data will be accepted.

I have searched the entire day and looked at things like async servlets, ServletContext listener and scheduledExecutorservice. I dont want to use scheduledExecutorService as it is invoked at app startUp which I dont want to do since this specific situation is a minor part of the code and to handle it I dont want something running all the time. I need some background service which keeps running even after the server has returned requested data.

Answer (score 0):

Servlets won't fulfill your requirements, therefore you should use `WebSockets`.
As per my understanding, you are trying to push data from the server, therefore you need to a `push` architecture instead of `pull` architecture (Servlets are based upon pull architecture).
Java has native support of [WebSockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/package-summary.html)
You can find several tutorials on how to use `WebSockets` in a Java Web Application.
Here is a link to a basic [WebSockets Tutorial](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html).

Hope this helps

Comment: No I am not trying to push data.